# How to select a specific Java version in java-gradle-plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

java-gradle-plugin exposes the api:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/index.html?overview-summary.html

Within the this API we have the JavaVersion for selecting the required Java-version.
(https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/JavaVersion.html)

Is it possible to select a specific version of Java-11? let's say Java 11.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

The `JavaVersion` enum only keeps track of the major version, not minor nor patch.